# Checkbox state saved in text file vb.net

Tags: vb.net, checkbox, text-files

This is my code:

```
    Private Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged
    Dim checkboxvalue As String = File.ReadAllText(Application.StartupPath + "\discordstatus.txt")
    If checkboxvalue = "1" Then
        CheckBox1.Checked = True
    End If

    If checkboxvalue = "0" Then
        CheckBox1.Checked = False
    End If

    If CheckBox1.Checked = "1" Then
        Dim fileReader As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(Application.StartupPath + "\discordstatus.txt").Replace("0", "1")
        My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(Application.StartupPath + "\discordstatus.txt", fileReader, False)
    End If

    If CheckBox1.Checked = "0" Then
        Dim fileReader As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(Application.StartupPath + "\discordstatus.txt").Replace("1", "0")
        My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(Application.StartupPath + "\discordstatus.txt", fileReader, False)
    End If
End Sub
```

I want it to (when unchecked) put 0 in the text file and (when checked) put a 1 in the text file, this code lets me control the status by changing the number in the file manually, but i cant check or uncheck the checkbox, please help.

Comment: you appear to be waiting for the user to click the checkbox, then reading the value from the file and setting the checkbox value, and then immediately testing the checkbox value and writing it back to the file. Your logic seems a bit mixed up. I'd have thought the bit where you load the value from the file and _set_ the checkbox value would occur when your form first loads, not when the user clicks.

Comment: you want the program immediately to restart when the user clicks? Can I ask why? Sounds unusual.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this automatically.

1. Go to design view and select your checkbx.
2. In the Properties window click the arrow by Application Settings.
3. Click new and set the default value and name of the setting.

The value of the check box will be automatically saved and set for you. No code.